# What are these levels of debug in Android (HI, MID, LOW) means

Tags: android

I have a question about level (deep) of debug in Android.
When I get in `SysDump tool` ( `*#9900# )` I can choose the level of debugging.
I can choose `low`, `mid` or `hi` level.  Depending on my choice I will get different `DumpState` file (with different information).

I need to know what these levels means. How can I use it in my code? For example with `low level` I will get one information in `dumpState` and if level is mid - another.

Where can I find an information about these levels?

Comment: Is this a Samsung device?

Comment: Yes! It's a Samsung device

Comment: I don't know anything about it, other than searching in the last few minutes. I appears that the Sysdump #9900# is peculiar to Samsung. You might try searching around with that in mind.